# MATLAB Report Generator can produce HTML but not PDF Report

Tags: matlab

I am just getting started with MATLAB Report Generator. I have completed the tutorial in chapter 2 (Magic Squares) of the MATLAB® Report Generator™ User's Guide, R2016a edition (http://www.mathworks.cn/help/pdf_doc/rptgen/rptgen.pdf), and successfully generated the HTML report.

I then went back and changed the File Format of the report from Web (HTML) to Acrobat (PDF), then clicked the Report tool to generate the same report in PDF format (without making any other changes).

This time, the report failed with the messages below. Is there some reason I can generate an HTML report but not a PDF report? How can I fix this?

```
Converting report
```

FATAL: "fo:block" is not a valid child of "fo:root"! (See position -1:-1)
org.apache.fop.fo.ValidationException: "fo:block" is not a valid child of "fo:root"! (See position -1:-1)
Document conversion failed. Java exception occurred:  ; SystemID: file:/Applications/MATLAB_R2016a.app/sys/namespace/docbook/v4/xsl/fo/mcode.xsl; Line#: 41; Column#: -1 javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: org.apache.fop.fo.ValidationException: "fo:block" is not a valid child of "fo:root"! (See position -1:-1)  at com.icl.saxon.style.StyleElement.styleError(StyleElement.java:818)  at com.icl.saxon.style.StyleElement.processChildren(StyleElement.java:645)  at com.icl.saxon.style.XSLTemplate.expand(XSLTemplate.java:229)  at com.icl.saxon.style.XSLTemplate.start(XSLTemplate.java:202)  at com.icl.saxon.Controller.applyTemplates(Controller.java:297)  at com.icl.saxon.style.XSLApplyTemplates.process(XSLApplyTemplates.java:139)  at com.icl.saxon.style.StyleElement.processChildren(StyleElement.java:643)  at com.icl.saxon.style.LiteralResultElement.process(LiteralResultElement.java:290)  at com.icl.saxon.style.StyleElement.processChildren(StyleElement.java:643)  at com.icl.saxon.style.XSLTemplate.expand(XSLTemplate.java:229)  at com.icl.saxon.style.XSLTemplate.start(XSLTemplate.java:202)  at com.icl.saxon.Controller.applyTemplates(Controller.java:297)  at com.icl.saxon.style.XSLApplyTemplates.process(XSLApplyTemplates.java:139)  at com.icl.saxon.style.StyleElement.processChildren(StyleElement.java:643)  at com.icl.saxon.style.XSLTemplate.expand(XSLTemplate.java:229)  at com.icl.saxon.style.XSLTemplate.start(XSLTemplate.java:202)  at com.icl.saxon.Controller.applyTemplates(Controller.java:288)  at com.icl.saxon.style.XSLApplyTemplates.process(XSLApplyTemplates.java:139)  at com.icl.saxon.style.StyleElement.processChildren(StyleElement.java:643)  at com.icl.saxon.style.LiteralResultElement.process(LiteralResultElement.java:290)  at com.icl.saxon.style.StyleElement.processChildren(StyleElement.java:643)  at com.icl.saxon.style.XSLTemplate.expand(XSLTemplate.java:229)  at com.icl.saxon.style.XSLTemplate.start(XSLTemplate.java:202)  at com.icl.saxon.Controller.applyTemplates(Controller.java:288)  at com.icl.saxon.Controller.defaultAction(Controller.java:313)  at com.icl.saxon.Controller.applyTemplates(Controller.java:278)  at com.icl.saxon.style.XSLApplyTemplates.process(XSLApplyTemplates.java:139)  at com.icl.saxon.style.StyleElement.processChildren(StyleElement.java:643)  at com.icl.saxon.style.XSLIf.process(XSLIf.java:78)  at com.icl.saxon.style.StyleElement.processChildren(StyleElement.java:643)  at com.icl.saxon.style.XSLOtherwise.process(XSLOtherwise.java:48)  at com.icl.saxon.style.XSLChoose.process(XSLChoose.java:96)  at com.icl.saxon.style.StyleElement.processChildren(StyleElement.java:643)  at com.icl.saxon.style.XSLOtherwise.process(XSLOtherwise.java:48)  at com.icl.saxon.style.XSLChoose.process(XSLChoose.java:96)  at com.icl.saxon.style.StyleElement.processChildren(StyleElement.java:643)  at com.icl.saxon.style.XSLOtherwise.process(XSLOtherwise.java:48)  at com.icl.saxon.style.XSLChoose.process(XSLChoose.java:96)  at com.icl.saxon.style.StyleElement.processChildren(StyleElement.java:643)  at com.icl.saxon.style.XSLTemplate.expand(XSLTemplate.java:229)  at com.icl.saxon.style.XSLTemplate.start(XSLTemplate.java:202)  at com.icl.saxon.Controller.applyImports(Controller.java:340)  at com.icl.saxon.style.XSLApplyImports.process(XSLApplyImports.java:68)  at com.icl.saxon.style.StyleElement.processChildren(StyleElement.java:643)  at com.icl.saxon.style.XSLOtherwise.process(XSLOtherwise.java:48)  at com.icl.saxon.style.XSLChoose.process(XSLChoose.java:96)  at com.icl.saxon.style.StyleElement.processChildren(StyleElement.java:643)  at com.icl.saxon.style.XSLTemplate.expand(XSLTemplate.java:229)  at com.icl.saxon.style.XSLTemplate.start(XSLTemplate.java:202)  at com.icl.saxon.Controller.applyTemplates(Controller.java:297)  at com.icl.saxon.Controller.run(Controller.java:220)  at com.icl.saxon.Controller.transformDocument(Controller.java:1125)  at com.icl.saxon.Controller.transform(Controller.java:994)  at com.mathworks.jmi.NativeMatlab.SendMatlabMessage(Native Method)  at com.mathworks.jmi.NativeMatlab.sendMatlabMessage(NativeMatlab.java:266)  at com.mathworks.jmi.MatlabLooper.sendMatlabMessage(MatlabLooper.java:120)  at com.mathworks.jmi.Matlab.mtFevalConsoleOutput(Matlab.java:1778)  at com.mathworks.jmi.MatlabMCR.mtFevalConsoleOutput(MatlabMCR.java:1232)  at com.mathworks.timer.MWCallback$callbackEvent.run(MWCallback.java:502)  at com.mathworks.jmi.NativeMatlab.dispatchMTRequests(NativeMatlab.java:458) Caused by: org.apache.fop.fo.ValidationException: "fo:block" is not a valid child of "fo:root"! (See position -1:-1)  at org.apache.fop.events.ValidationExceptionFactory.createException(Unknown Source)  at org.apache.fop.events.EventExceptionManager.throwException(Unknown Source)  at org.apache.fop.events.DefaultEventBroadcaster$1.invoke(Unknown Source)  at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy29.invalidChild(Unknown Source)  at org.apache.fop.fo.FONode.invalidChildError(Unknown Source)  at org.apache.fop.fo.FONode.invalidChildError(Unknown Source)  at org.apache.fop.fo.pagination.Root.validateChildNode(Unknown Source)  at org.apache.fop.fo.FOTreeBuilder$MainFOHandler.startElement(Unknown Source)  at org.apache.fop.fo.FOTreeBuilder.startElement(Unknown Source)  at com.icl.saxon.output.ContentHandlerProxy.startElement(ContentHandlerProxy.java:129)  at com.icl.saxon.output.ProxyEmitter.startElement(ProxyEmitter.java:80)  at com.icl.saxon.output.NamespaceEmitter.startElement(NamespaceEmitter.java:95)  at com.icl.saxon.output.GeneralOutputter.flushStartTag(GeneralOutputter.java:745)  at com.icl.saxon.output.GeneralOutputter.writeStartTag(GeneralOutputter.java:506)  at com.icl.saxon.style.LiteralResultElement.process(LiteralResultElement.java:266)  at com.icl.saxon.style.StyleElement.processChildren(StyleElement.java:643)  ... 58 more --------- org.apache.fop.fo.ValidationException: "fo:block" is not a valid child of "fo:root"! (See position -1:-1)  at org.apache.fop.events.ValidationExceptionFactory.createException(Unknown Source)  at org.apache.fop.events.EventExceptionManager.throwException(Unknown Source)  at org.apache.fop.events.DefaultEventBroadcaster$1.invoke(Unknown Source)  at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy29.invalidChild(Unknown Source)  at org.apache.fop.fo.FONode.invalidChildError(Unknown Source)  at org.apache.fop.fo.FONode.invalidChildError(Unknown Source)  at org.apache.fop.fo.pagination.Root.validateChildNode(Unknown Source)  at org.apache.fop.fo.FOTreeBuilder$MainFOHandler.startElement(Unknown Source)  at org.apache.fop.fo.FOTreeBuilder.startElement(Unknown Source)  at com.icl.saxon.output.ContentHandlerProxy.startElement(ContentHandlerProxy.java:129)  at com.icl.saxon.output.ProxyEmitter.startElement(ProxyEmitter.java:80)  at com.icl.saxon.output.NamespaceEmitter.startElement(NamespaceEmitter.java:95)  at com.icl.saxon.output.GeneralOutputter.flushStartTag(GeneralOutputter.java:745)  at com.icl.saxon.output.GeneralOutputter.writeStartTag(GeneralOutputter.java:506)  at com.icl.saxon.style.LiteralResultElement.process(LiteralResultElement.java:266)  at com.icl.saxon.style.StyleElement.processChildren(StyleElement.java:643)  at com.icl.saxon.style.XSLTemplate.expand(XSLTemplate.java:229)  at com.icl.saxon.style.XSLTemplate.start(XSLTemplate.java:202)  at com.icl.saxon.Controller.applyTemplates(Controller.java:297)  at com.icl.saxon.style.XSLApplyTemplates.process(XSLApplyTemplates.java:139)  at com.icl.saxon.style.StyleElement.processChildren(StyleElement.java:643)  at com.icl.saxon.style.LiteralResultElement.process(LiteralResultElement.java:290)  at com.icl.saxon.style.StyleElement.processChildren(StyleElement.java:643)  at com.icl.saxon.style.XSLTemplate.expand(XSLTemplate.java:229)  at com.icl.saxon.style.XSLTemplate.start(XSLTemplate.java:202)  at com.icl.saxon.Controller.applyTemplates(Controller.java:297)  at com.icl.saxon.style.XSLApplyTemplates.process(XSLApplyTemplates.java:139)  at com.icl.saxon.style.StyleElement.processChildren(StyleElement.java:643)  at com.icl.saxon.style.XSLTemplate.expand(XSLTemplate.java:229)  at com.icl.saxon.style.XSLTemplate.start(XSLTemplate.java:202)  at com.icl.saxon.Controller.applyTemplates(Controller.java:288)  at com.icl.saxon.style.XSLApplyTemplates.process(XSLApplyTemplates.java:139)  at com.icl.saxon.style.StyleElement.processChildren(StyleElement.java:643)  at com.icl.saxon.style.LiteralResultElement.process(LiteralResultElement.java:290)  at com.icl.saxon.style.StyleElement.processChildren(StyleElement.java:643)  at com.icl.saxon.style.XSLTemplate.expand(XSLTemplate.java:229)  at com.icl.saxon.style.XSLTemplate.start(XSLTemplate.java:202)  at com.icl.saxon.Controller.applyTemplates(Controller.java:288)  at com.icl.saxon.Controller.defaultAction(Controller.java:313)  at com.icl.saxon.Controller.applyTemplates(Controller.java:278)  at com.icl.saxon.style.XSLApplyTemplates.process(XSLApplyTemplates.java:139)  at com.icl.saxon.style.StyleElement.processChildren(StyleElement.java:643)  at com.icl.saxon.style.XSLIf.process(XSLIf.java:78)  at com.icl.saxon.style.StyleElement.processChildren(StyleElement.java:643)  at com.icl.saxon.style.XSLOtherwise.process(XSLOtherwise.java:48)  at com.icl.saxon.style.XSLChoose.process(XSLChoose.java:96)  at com.icl.saxon.style.StyleElement.processChildren(StyleElement.java:643)  at com.icl.saxon.style.XSLOtherwise.process(XSLOtherwise.java:48)  at com.icl.saxon.style.XSLChoose.process(XSLChoose.java:96)  at com.icl.saxon.style.StyleElement.processChildren(StyleElement.java:643)  at com.icl.saxon.style.XSLOtherwise.process(XSLOtherwise.java:48)  at com.icl.saxon.style.XSLChoose.process(XSLChoose.java:96)  at com.icl.saxon.style.StyleElement.processChildren(StyleElement.java:643)  at com.icl.saxon.style.XSLTemplate.expand(XSLTemplate.java:229)  at com.icl.saxon.style.XSLTemplate.start(XSLTemplate.java:202)  at com.icl.saxon.Controller.applyImports(Controller.java:340)  at com.icl.saxon.style.XSLApplyImports.process(XSLApplyImports.java:68)  at com.icl.saxon.style.StyleElement.processChildren(StyleElement.java:643)  at com.icl.saxon.style.XSLOtherwise.process(XSLOtherwise.java:48)  at com.icl.saxon.style.XSLChoose.process(XSLChoose.java:96)  at com.icl.saxon.style.StyleElement.processChildren(StyleElement.java:643)  at com.icl.saxon.style.XSLTemplate.expand(XSLTemplate.java:229)  at com.icl.saxon.style.XSLTemplate.start(XSLTemplate.java:202)  at com.icl.saxon.Controller.applyTemplates(Controller.java:297)  at com.icl.saxon.Controller.run(Controller.java:220)  at com.icl.saxon.Controller.transformDocument(Controller.java:1125)  at com.icl.saxon.Controller.transform(Controller.java:994)  at com.mathworks.jmi.NativeMatlab.SendMatlabMessage(Native Method)  at com.mathworks.jmi.NativeMatlab.sendMatlabMessage(NativeMatlab.java:266)  at com.mathworks.jmi.MatlabLooper.sendMatlabMessage(MatlabLooper.java:120)  at com.mathworks.jmi.Matlab.mtFevalConsoleOutput(Matlab.java:1778)  at com.mathworks.jmi.MatlabMCR.mtFevalConsoleOutput(MatlabMCR.java:1232)  at com.mathworks.timer.MWCallback$callbackEvent.run(MWCallback.java:502)  at com.mathworks.jmi.NativeMatlab.dispatchMTRequests(NativeMatlab.java:458)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to Paul Kinnucan who answered my question here: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/277833-how-can-i-use-matlab-report-generator-to-produce-pdf-report-rather-than-html-report#answer_221920 .

There was an error in the Eval component at the beginning of the report. That error was ignored when generating HTML, but was fatal when generating PDF. After correcting the error, I was able to generate a PDF report.